# Formulário no Laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel-5, formulário, laravel-5.4, laravel-collective

Estou tendo um grande dificuldade ao tentar criar um formulário no `Laravel` 5.4, na hora de carregar a `View` aparece o seguinte erro:

> "ErrorException in helpers.php line 532: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View:/var/www/html/controle/resources/views/users/create.blade.php)"

Minha `View` está assim:

```
<div>
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'users')) }}

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('name', 'Name') }}
        {{ Form::text('name', array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('email', 'Email') }}
        {{ Form::email('email', array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('nerd_level', 'User Level') }}
        {{ Form::select('nerd_level', array('0' => 'Nomal', '1' => 'Admin'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
    </div>

    {{ Form::submit('Create the User!', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}

{{ Form::close() }}
</div>
```

Alguém saberia informar como consertar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O segundo parametro de `email`, `text` ou `textarea` sempre receberá o valor atual que preenche o `input`.

Nesse caso, substitua por `Form::text('nome', null, array('class' => 'x'))`

Aqui vai uma sinopse pra simplificar

```
Form::text($nome_do_campo, $valor_do_campo, $attributos)
```

Acompanhe na imagem que retirei da documentação (referêncais futuras caso a documentação quebre o link):

[image: Parâmetro do form builder do laravel]

Veja o link da documentação:

- https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Html/FormBuilder.html

Comment: `Form::email` também né?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sim, todos eles. É que o segundo parâmetro equivale ao `value` do `input`. Só o `Form::select` que muda a ordem, que no caso é no terceiro parâmetro.

Comment: agora funcionou, mas quando eu clico no botão, a pagina se recarrega e os dados não são salvos no banco!

Comment: @Samueldesouza aí seria outro problema. Sugiro que faça uma nova pergunta